# Get value from string via xpath in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xpath

I have a html page as string like below;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

and I want to get value from that string via xPath. Xpath like below;

```
/html/body/p
```

Result has to be ;

> This is a paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem as below. I wrote a method which is convert html to element.

```
function htmlToElement(html) {
    var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, "text/html");
    return doc;
}
```

I got value like below.

```
var doc = htmlToElement(htmlString);
xPath = "/html/body/p";
var value = doc.evaluate(xPath, doc, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null).iterateNext().innerHTML;
```